Unable to change the context root URL of Apache Superset
Unable to change the context root of Apache Superset. I am aiming to run the superset app on localhost:8088/myapp instead of the default localhost:8088
Tried various approaches by including some available properties/flags in the config file. Below is my superset_config.py file. At the end, switched the approach to creating a Nginx reverse-proxy but that resulted in Error 404. If anyone has done something similar, please drop a solution below.
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
    SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_BASEURL = '/myapp/'
    FEATURE_FLAGS = {
        "EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True,
        "RELATIVE_URLS": True,
    }
    APPLICATION_ROOT = '/myapp'
    APPLICATION_ROOT = '/myapp'
    RELATIVE_URLS=True
    WEBSERVER_CONTEXT_ROOT = "/myapp"
    WEBSERVER_PROXY_PREFIX = "/myapp"
    WEBSERVER_CONTEXT_ROOT = "/myapp"
    WEBDRIVER_BASEURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp"


Did you find the the solution for this? I am struggling for same.
